# highchartr: Synchronize point and line colors and legend

Tags: highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I'm using the `highchartr` package to create an interactive chart.

My chart has lines on it corresponding to different series.  In addition, I would like to have shapes at certain points on the lines.

Its very easy to get the points in the right place. However, I would like to map the point color to the line it is associated with. And when the user clicks on the legend entry for the line, I'd like the associated points to be toggled as well.

The code looks like this:

```
 highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series(
      type="line",
      marker=list(enabled=F),
      data=input_data, 
      mapping=hcaes(x=x, y=y, group=series_name)
    ) %>%
    hc_add_series(
      type="point", 
      data=input_data %>% filter(! is.na(marker)), 
      mapping=hcaes(x=x, y=y, color=series_name, fill=series_name, group=series_name, shape=marker)
    )
```

The result gets the points in the right place. But the point color is on a different color mapping from the lines. Clicking on the entry for the line in the legend toggles only the line - the points show up as separate entries by `series_name`.

[image]

What

What can I do so:
-   The points and lines share the same color mapping
-   The points and lines can be toggled together by clicking on the line in the legend
-   The points show up separately in the legend based on their shape rather than their color?

Thanks!

Comment: you still haven't provided your data. How someone can work on your example and give you the answer when we can't even run your code?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it can be achieved in at least few different ways. It all depends on your data which you haven't provided (I created a sample data).

Additionally, I will provide all the examples in jsFiddle (JavaScript) because it is faster to explain something that way with a quick online example.
**The final answer will contain R code** (maybe with some custom JavaScript if needed, but all will be reproducible in R.

---

First of all, your assumption that you need a separate series is wrong and causes problems. If you want markers on your line with the same color and you want to toggle them together on legend click, then you don't need separate series - **one series with markers enabled on some points is enough**, see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s24rk9x7/
In this case, the R data needs to be defined properly.

---

If you don't want to keep it simple as described above, you can keep lines and markers as separate series as in your original question.
In this case, you can use [series.linkedTo](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo) property to connect your "point" series to line series (BTW in Highcharts there is no something like **"point"** series type, it is **"scatter"** series type. Another reason why your code is wrong and is not working and you got unvoted), but there is a problem with it in Highcharter - doesn't work, seems like a bug and should be reported on Highcharter GitHub repo.

This is a JavaScript version which works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3mtdfqLo/
In this example, if you want to keep markers and line series in the same color, you can define colors manually or you can write some custom code (like I did) that will change the color for you automatically.

And this is the same R version which should work, but is not:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data=list(4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3)
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data=list(14, 13, 15, 16, 12, 13),
    id="first"
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data=list(10, 8, 6, 2, 5, 12),
    id="second"
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type="scatter",
    linkedTo="first",
    data=list(list(1, 3), list(2, 5))
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type="scatter",
    linkedTo="second",
    data=list(list(1, 13), list(2, 15), list(3, 16))
  ) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    line = list(marker=list(enabled=F))
  )
```

There is probably something wrong with `hc_add_series` function.
**As a workaround**, you can write it all as a custom JavaScript code, which (again) works fine:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    line = list(marker=list(enabled=F))
  ) %>%
  hc_chart(
    events = list(load = JS("function() {

        this.addSeries({
          data: [4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3],
          id: 'first'
        });

        this.addSeries({
          data: [14, 13, 15, 16, 12, 13],
          id: 'second'
        });

        this.addSeries({
          data: [10, 8, 6, 2, 5, 12]
        });

        this.addSeries({
          type: 'scatter',
          linkedTo: 'first',
          data: [[1, 3], [2, 5]]
        });

        this.addSeries({
          type: 'scatter',
          linkedTo: 'second',
          data: [[1, 13], [2, 15], [3, 16]]
        });

    }")))
```

Of course, last examples don't contain functionality that changes colors - you can copy it from the jsFiddle above.

Comment: This answer is, to be clear, just wrong, because it misunderstands that this is not a static chart, but a dynamic one, that is fed reactive data.

Comment: Again, to be clear:  I'm not inviting you to improve it!  The issues here are fundamental.  I'm just responding as a warning to anyone who happens upon this question and might otherwise waste time on this answer.